# How to reset an image after the function has finished

Tags: javascript, html

[Here](http://thecodingninja.com/muslim/practice.php), you see an image that says "Type in the box" you type click enter everything works.

After it is done I want it to show the image again. 
I have this code:

```
function imageReset() {
    $("#image").reset(); 
}
```

I do not know how to make it run automatically after it has finished spelling the word

```
function setLetter(letter) {
  var img = document.getElementById("image");
  if (letter && letter.length == 1) {
    img.src =       "http://thecodingninja.com/muslim/fingerspellingimg/"+letter+"abc.jpg";
  }
  else {
    img.src = "";
  }
}

function nextLetter(word) {
  if (word.length > 0) {
    var firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
    setLetter(firstLetter);
    setTimeout(nextLetter, 1000, word.substring(1));
  }
  else {
    setLetter();

  }
    }

function spellWord() {
  var word = document.getElementById("text").value;
  nextLetter(word.toUpperCase());
  }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with php.. Please refer to the correct tag

Comment: can you post the javascript function that is running to display the sequence of images?

Comment: Edited and added code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think all you would need to do is set it on line 7

```
function setLetter(letter) {
  var img = document.getElementById("image");
  if (letter && letter.length == 1) {
    img.src =       "http://thecodingninja.com/muslim/fingerspellingimg/"+letter+"abc.jpg";
  }
  else {
    img.src = "/muslim/fingerspellingimg/HDabc.jpg"; // <-- right here
  }
}
```

The logic flows that it'll hit that at the very end after the word is complete.

Comment: Thanks. I am dumb.

Comment: @MuslimTwin lol nah. Logic can get confusing like that especially if you have to follow it through a couple of functions.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the source back in the else check of `nextLetter` function.

```
function nextLetter(word) {
  if (word.length > 0) {
    var firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
    setLetter(firstLetter);
    setTimeout(nextLetter, 1000, word.substring(1));
  }
  else {
     $("#image").attr('src',"fingerspellingimg/HDabc.jpg");  // set here instead of calling the setLetter again.
  }
 }
```

So once the above is done you can just keep your function `setLetter` simple as below

```
function setLetter(letter) {        
    document.getElementById("image").src = "http://thecodingninja.com/muslim/fingerspellingimg/"+letter+"abc.jpg";     
}
```

or you can move this line of code into your `nextLetter` function itself, hence there is no need of this function at all.